# Limit with denominator = $0$

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

Prove that :

$$\lim_{x\to t} \frac{f(x)-m}{x-t} = k$$

if $k \in C ( or R)$ than $f(t) = m $

Comment: i don't know why did you marked this as "on hold". It is quite clear to me. I already have my answer.

Comment: Read the bulleted message in the highlighted text, @Crazy_39365, *before* asking "why on hold?"   You need to take more initiative when asking questions, as described in the bulleted message you received, and in researching prior to posting questions, or, in the case of your question in the comments, above, merely reading what's right in front of your nose, before asking for explanations.

Comment: okay thanks for your feedback i'll try to be more careful. P.S: english is not my mother language that is why i asked for an explanation. Some of the words mean different in translates etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that if

$$f(x)\to n\neq m \implies \lim_{x\to t} \frac{f(x)-m}{x-t} = \pm \infty
$$

thus we need that $f(x)\to m$ but note that this is a necessary but not a sufficient condition.

Indeed for example assuming

$$f(x)=m+|x-t|\implies \lim_{x\to t} \frac{f(x)-m}{x-t}=\lim_{x\to t} \frac{|x-t|}{x-t}$$

which doesn't exist.

Comment: so we can't exactly prove it ?

Comment: @Crazy_39365 We can prove that $$\lim_{x\to t} \frac{f(x)-m}{x-t} = k \implies f(x)\to m$$ by contradiction assuming that $f(x)\to n\neq m$ what is not true is that  $$\lim_{x\to t} \frac{f(x)-m}{x-t} = k \iff f(x)\to m$$